# viewcontroller won't dismiss

Tags: iphone

I have the following code

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   NSLog(@"dismiss view");
   [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

This prints dismiss view but won't execute the view dismissal code.

Can a view be dismissed in code without a trigger from an IBAction?

Why wouldn't this be executing?

Comment: Could you post the code that presents the modal view controller?

Comment: Im not sure if it is that, because I have a method called closeView which I call when a "back" button is pressed and this dismisses the view correctly. If I call the closeview method in the viewWillAppear method, it doesnt execute. Is it possible that a view cant be dismissed when called in a viewWillAppear?

Comment: why would you be dismissing the view in its viewWillAppear method?

Comment: Because I need to dismiss 2 views at once. example. View1 presents view2, View2 presents view3. Then when something is selected, I need to dismiss both views and go back to view1

Comment: So into which view controller did you put this method? If it is "View2" then how are you going to present View2 the first time?

Comment: I use a BOOL to check if something was selected in view3.

Comment: Can you post more code please? We need a clearer idea of what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably have better luck putting the code into `viewDidAppear` rather than `viewWillAppear`. The latter tends to be called right at the start of any animation such as a modal beginning to slide off the screen; the former tends to be called when that animation has completely finished. Note that even if this strategy works, you may end up with a weird effect whereby two modals are seen to slide off, one after the other; I presume you just want one sliding off effect.

What happens if you dismiss the "lower down" modal dialog (the one first pushed), and don't bother dismissing the one that is topmost?

Also consider paying attention to the `animated` argument when dismissing your modal view controller. Different combinations of animated or not can have different effects when you have problems like yours.

If you post a more complete code sample we can give a better answer!

Comment: Perfect, thanks. :) moved the code to viewDidAppear and it works.

Answer (score 0):

try with a little delay on the second dismiss.

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   NSLog(@"dismiss view");
   [self performSelector:@selector(delayedDismiss) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
}

-(void)delayedDismiss{
   [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: I don't recommend this strategy particularly -- putting in arbitrary  delays to make something work is a code smell. There's usually a better way. (Which exact way is hard to know given the limited amount of info the OP gives.)

Comment: I think the calls are overlaped and the same modal view controller gets the two calls. The second one needs time to be the responder. Just a solution, I know is not the better one but it is the easier. I think you have to review your implementation.